# Not able to install fabric-sdk-go and its dependencies

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I am trying to download `fabric-sdk-go` library and all its dependency with the below command in a linux VM.

```
go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/...
```

It is giving the below error.

```
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations
../github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations/system.go:227:23: not enough arguments in call to s.statsd.SendLoop
        have (<-chan time.Time, string, string)
        want (context.Context, <-chan time.Time, string, string)
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util
../github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util/csp.go:47:8: cannot convert nil to type csr.KeyRequest
../github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util/csp.go:132:37: cannot use req.KeyRequest (type *csr.KeyRequest) as type csr.KeyRequest in argument to getBCCSPKeyOpts
```

Could this be because of `go` version mismatch or something? Here is the `go version` I am using the in linux VM.

```
go version go1.12.8 linux/amd64
```

Comment: I just tried with `go version go1.11.4 darwin/amd64` and it installed correctly. I am on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

If modules aren't turned on, `go get` will grab the incorrect version of some dependencies. As will most other dependency tools.

The first error `# github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations` is due to go-kit differences between v0.8.0 and v0.9.0.

The second error `# github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util` is due to a more recent version of cfssl than supported.

The sdk doesn't have an actual binary output, so we shouldn't be `go get`'ting it in any case.